# UISplitViewController popover menu fills screen, how to change the size?

Tags: ios, ipad, uisplitviewcontroller, uipopovercontroller

I'm not sure what I did, because this used to work fine, but all of a sudden the popover menus in portrait orientation are filling the screen. Previously it would only be as big as the xib (320px), but now they cover the entire screen. (The xib for the table view controller contained in the popover.)

I don't think I have any code that controls this. Do you have any suggestions as to where I should look?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

May be this will help you: from Apple Documentation:

```
@property(nonatomic, readwrite) CGSize contentSizeForViewInPopover
```

> This property contains the desired size for the view controller when it is displayed in a popover. By default, the width is set to 320 points and the height is set to 1100 points. You can change these values as needed.

Comment: Right, I'm familiar with that property, but I was never having to set it before in this context. I've added some lines in to set the size explicitly. Usually, I just set it to self.view.frame.size so that the popover defaults the size the underlying xib, but the underlying xib appears to be getting resized automatically.

Comment: what a property to include in the _stock UIViewController Class_ as iffff it wouldn't size the popover to `(*UIViewController).view`s dimensions or in the `presentPopoverFromRect:rect` dimensions... thank you very much for finding this!